Rust compiler installation
I am trying to install rustup on Ubuntu but when I run the command curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh, I get the following error:
kdsouza@bsc-848851112:/$ sudo curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
info: downloading installer
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
rustup: command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.byP7Lz97VD/rustup-init x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

How do I fix this?
Thank you in advance

Why are you running curl with sudo here?

@steeldriver I think they meant to have sudo on the other side of the pipe... @OP as I said, you probably need sudo to run that script, not to run the curl command.

Well I'll take it back, apparently that's not installing it system-wide (I tried it and it works for me), so you shouldn't need sudo at all here. Not sure about the error though

If not installing system wide, then you should probably be in your user's $HOME directory ~/ instead of / so just run cd or cd ~/ before you run the curl stuff.
Your user does not own or have permission to write files to your current directory which is your root directory /. You can see your current directory indicated before the dollar sign at your prompt kdsouza@bsc-848851112:/$
Any one of the following sets of commands listed below will do the same thing, that is, change to your user's home directory before downloading and running the installation script. Your user's home directory will be indicated by the tilde sign ~ as your current directory shown at ypur prompt kdsouza@bsc-848851112:~$
cd
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

or
cd ~/
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

or
cd $HOME
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

Running the cd command with no directory specified (first command) shoud change to your home directory by default.
Alternatively, running the cd command along with a directory will change to whatever directory you specify. Your user's home directory is /home/username/ where username is your current username so probably /home/kdsouza.
$HOME and ~ and ~/ and even /home/$USER will all be interpreted by bash as the same thing, /home/kdsouza. So you can cd to any one of these to get to your home directory.

Either that or there's no space left on your device although it usually says something like no space left on device in the output when that is the case.
To view your available free space, run the following command:
df -h

The -h flag will list the free space in human readable format.

I'll try and test the "you're in /" possible explanation (I have to figure out how to uninstall the thing first, as currently, if I try to run the thing from / everything runs smoothly, however I have the thing installed altready); the missing disk space also makes sense: it appears as though it's the curl getting called by the script that's failing at something, so perhaps that could be writing to /tmp as the output suggests...

Hey, thank you. This worked for me

Unless you need the latest, bleeding edge version of Rust, do apt-cache search rust to see which Ubuntu packages provide which versions of rust. For initial learning, one doesn't need the absolute latest, and it's "best" if you don't "accidentally" find yourself at war (or confusion) with the packaging system.

Based on the output:
command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.byP7Lz97VD/rustup-init x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

It seems as though the script is silently failing between line 600 - 620.
If this turns out to be correct I'll post a full breakdown of why I think this is the case, however since I didn't go as deep as to find the super-specific reason why it would be failing (yet), for now I'll just suggest what, if I'm right, could be the solution.
Try to force the script to use wget instead of curl to fetch the additional files it needs. This can be done by running this command instead (it will dynamically inject a line into the downloaded script to make this happen):
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs | sed '592s/^/_dld=wget/' | sh


Otherwise, to do the same manually:
Download the script:
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs >rustup-init.sh

change line 592 of the downloaded rustup-init.sh file (which is an empty line) to:
_dld=wget

and manually run the script:
sh rustup-init.sh

